# Is there a Dataflow source ack API?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

As per [shutdown and update job in Google Dataflow with PubSubIO + message guarantees](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33362730/shutdown-and-update-job-in-google-dataflow-with-pubsubio-message-guarantees/33375977#33375977) the pub/sub source for dataflow does not ack messages until they have been reliably persisted. Is there any possibility for manual control over this? We're persisting rows as a side-effect in a ParDo as there is currently no unbounded custom sink support, is there any way for us to mark that ParDo as "on bundle processing success ack these records"?

Alternatively, could we persist as a side-effect in a ParDo, if it fails throw an exception, and then after that ParDo in the pipeline have some sort of "dummy" streaming sink like BigQuery to make sure the messages are ack'd? Would throwing exceptions as part of "normal, expected behaviour" lead to new problems?

Is the answer here really "just wait for unbounded custom sink support"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe Dataflow automatically gives the behavior you want. We will not ack PubSub messages until we have finished processing them with your `ParDo`'s and persisted the results.

Comment: Right. But if we're persisting the results as a side-effect of the pardo because there's currently no support for custom unbounded sinks?

Comment: Are you running a pipeline and not seeing ACKs? As far as I know, we should be acking as soon as it has been persisted within the Dataflow pipeline, independent of what your code is doing. Further, even if ACKs depended on being persisted, then as soon as the ParDo finished processing the inputs it would be ACKed. Note that your ParDo needs to tolerant of duplicates due to retries (eg., exceptions, etc.).

Comment: This post led me to believe that messages are not ack'd until they have been either emitted by a sink or persisted by a groupby. In a pipeline with no groupby and no sink I took that to mean they'd never be ack'd, am I wrong in this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33362730/shutdown-and-update-job-in-google-dataflow-with-pubsubio-message-guarantees/33375977#33375977

Comment: They are ACKed as soon as the bundle they are in is completed -- so even if they're filtered out and don't get written, they are still ACKed as soon as the bundle is committed. In practice, this means after they are used as the input to a GroupByKey, emitted by a sink, or processed by the last ParDo in a pipeline (approximately similar to writing them to /dev/null). Essentially, as soon as the elements are processed by the first fused step (see [Service Optimization](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/service/dataflow-service-desc#fusion-optimization) for details on fused steps).

Comment: *right* ok that's really good to know. So if I have a pardo that uses the BQ API to "try insert, if fail try updating schema, try insert, if fail exception" that will basically do what I want. awesome (assuming I don't care about duplicates, which I don't)

Comment: The behavior you described will cause bundles which throw an exception to be retried. In Streaming these bundles will be retried forever. In a Batch pipeline it will eventually fail the job. Depending on your needs, you may want to just [log the problem](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/examples/wordcount-example#using-cloud-logging) and continue, or write it to a different location (a [dead letter file](https://cloud.google.com/blog/big-data/2016/01/handling-invalid-inputs-in-dataflow)).