# Write To BigQuery retry on transform or stage?

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

Lets say that we have dataflow streaming pipeline which reads data from pubsub, transforms it in pardo and writes to BQ.
Also lets assume that dataflow optimizer squashes all of those steps into single stage.

My questions is: if the final step - WriteToBigQuery - fails and we have set retry strategy, reprocess will only the final step or the whole stage, so in fact element will be reprocessed from the beginning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When planning execution, Dataflow will not end up fusing all of these into a single stage. If I recall correctly, the PubsubIO input stage always involves a shuffle (GroupByKey) in order to distribute load. Likewise for the output `WriteToBigQuery` step. Each GroupByKey operation will checkpoint state in the Dataflow job.

If your dataflow job fails in the WriteToBigQuery stage, it will have already read pubsub messages and acked them in the first GroupByKey. If you retry the job, it will not re-read the pubsub message that were already acked. You would need to unack the pubsub messages using a seek operation (if you have retention set on the topic) or you would need to replay the messages from an upstream system.

See some more detail on this in [Recover PubSub Acked messages from Dataflow after a region loss](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60624824/recover-pubsub-acked-messages-from-dataflow-after-a-region-loss/60636950#60636950)